How to start R Markdown HTML section numbering not at 1
I am working in an R Markdown document. I am using the standard markdown headings (e.g. # First Heading) and using the
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: true

option in my YAML header to get the sections numbered in my output HTML file. I also included a LaTeX chunk to start the heading numbering at 5, instead of 1:
```{=latex}
\setcounter{section}{5}
```

before my first section header. However, when I knit the document to HTML, the section numbers start at 1, instead of at 5. How can I get them to start at 5?

If you convert to html, latex isn't at all involved.

Does number_offset work?
